# How to write custom json serializer and serialize value as an array

Tags: java, json, serialization

I need to serialize simple java object with three fields (one is a List of objects) into json to look something like this:

```
{
"id": "1",
"fields": [
    {
        "value": {
                "someNumber": "0.0.2"
            },
        "id": "67"
    }
],
"name": "Daniel"}
```

I've read guides on custom serializers StdSerializer and JsonGenerator, as i undestood, to write `"name": "Daniel"` into json you need to do somwthing like `gen.writeObjectField("name", name);` but i cannot get my head on two things:

1. How to write some string value like here:

   ```
       "value": {
         "name": "0.0.2"
       },
   ```
2. And how to write java List as an array like this:

   ```
   "fields": [
   {
       "value": {
               "someNumber": "0.0.2"
           },
       "id": "67"
   }]
   ```

where "fields" is an List full of objects having two fields: "value" and "id".
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String ret;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonGenerator jg = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(new PrintWriter(bos));

        jg.writeStartObject();

        jg.writeStringField("id", "1");

        jg.writeArrayFieldStart("fields");

        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeObjectFieldStart("value");
        jg.writeStringField("someNumber","0.0.2");
        jg.writeEndObject();
        jg.writeStringField("id","67");
        jg.writeEndObject();

        //you can write more objects in fields here
        jg.writeEndArray();

        jg.writeStringField("name","Daniel");

        jg.writeEndObject();

        jg.flush();
        jg.close();

        ret = bos.toString();
        bos.close();
        System.out.println(ret);

    }
}
```

and the result is

```json
{
    "id":"1",
    "fields":[
        {
            "value":{
                "someNumber":"0.0.2"
            },
            "id":"67"
        }
    ],
    "name":"Daniel"
}
```